# Manipulating dotx templates with C#

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk, word-template

I have a problem,

I have a .dotx file which has been supplied by customers. It contains a number of fields of different kinds added in developermode in Word.

I want to be able to use this dotx and fill it up with values.

How do I do this in C#-code?

Comment: Are there any limitions about what you are allowed to work with. For example installing Office on a server/client that will run your program?

Comment: Well, I can install office etc on server/client. But the important stuff is that the data is coming from a database or a webform. Therefor I need to be able to manipulate the dotx from code in order to generate finished documents.

Comment: @Bali C, I have, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Microsoft OpemXML SDK allows you to manipulate docx/dotx files using c#. You can download the Microsoft OpenXML SDK from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124).

You should first create a copy of your dotx file. Then find the fields/content palceholders in  the template.

Here is a small example (using a simple word template with a rich text box content field):

```
// First, create a copy of your template.
File.Copy(@"c:\temp\mytemplate.dotx", @"c:\temp\test.docx", true);

using (WordprocessingDocument newdoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"c:\temp\test.docx", true))
{
  // Change document type (dotx->docx)
  newdoc.ChangeDocumentType(WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);

  // Find all structured document tags
  IEnumerable<SdtContentRun> placeHolders = newdoc.MainDocumentPart.RootElement.Descendants<SdtContentRun>();

  foreach (var cp in placeHolders)
  {
    var r = cp.Descendants<Run>().FirstOrDefault();

    r.RemoveAllChildren(); // Remove children
    r.AppendChild<Text>(new Text("my text")); // add new content
  }        
}
```

The example above is a very simple example. You have to adapt it to your word template structure.

Hope, this helps.

Comment: I found this yesterday and it worked pretty nicely with what I have atm.
http://midnightprogrammer.net/post/Word-Automation-in-C.aspx
But I will havea a look at this aswell, it might work better for me. Thanks!